# How to start Ubuntu One indicator from command line

Tags: ubuntu-one, i3-wm, indicator-syc

I'm switching to [i3 window manager](http://i3wm.org/). I want to use the `indicator-sync` tool from within that desktop environment, but I couldn't find the executable for it. Where is it? Thanks in advance.

**update**: I've found `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sync/indicator-sync-service`, but it fails with the followin error when called from command line:

```
libindicator-WARNING **: No watchers, service timing out.
```

Comment: I have this exact problem, an dI'm not switching to i3 window manager :p